# CSS Border Color chrome/firefox

Tags: css, colors

If I give a border bottom color it appears a lot darker as i defined it. In safari mobile it appears as i had defined it. Is there a way to influence this behavior?

```
border-bottom-width: 4px;
border-bottom-color: #f00;
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

[image: appearance HTML]

[image: CSS]

[image: HTML]

Comment: See chrome inspect.

Comment: that was my first clue, but there is nothing which is telling me what i do wrong

Comment: what is the `border-bottom-color` property value in chrome developer tool? `#f00`?

Comment: I don't see any problem with the code you show. Please put up a working snippet and make sure it includes enough to show the problem. The image you give looks as though there is some sort of filter or overlying semi transparent pale blue element.

Comment: Thank you for your quick respond. I try to make it more transparent

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
    <title>Titel</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   
<?php

  echo'
  <input class="testinput">
  ';

?>

  </body>
</html>

Comment: .testinput {
 
 border-color: greenyellow;
 border-width: 10px;
 margin: 80px 100px;
}

Comment: i added a additional screenshot to show my problem :-)

Comment: the left and top border is way darker as the bottom and the right border and i try to figure out why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your problem lies in original Chrome/FF style for inputs - borders specifically. Just specify the `border-style` as `solid` and it should give you the desired output

```css
.testinput { border: 10px solid greenyellow;
margin: 80px 100px; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="de"> <head> <meta charset="utf-8"> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css"> <title>Titel</title> </head> <body> <input class="testinput"/> </body> </html>
```

Comment: OMG that easy :-o ok i have to learn a lot more before asking for help.

Comment: THANK YOU !!!!!